# How to exclude words from project search in Atom editor?

Tags: search, atom-editor

I press Shift + CMD + F in my Atom Editor (on OS X) to search for the term "aria" within all files of my project.

Now I also get search results for "Variant" which is not what I want, so I want to exclude the word variant from my search.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "whole word" option (ctr + alt + w, or click on the button on the far right in the project search options)

[image]